# datagridview New Column which on every row assigns the number of row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working on a C# project, and I have a DataGridview in which I am adding dynamically a new column with the following code.

```cs
DataGridViewColumn cl = new DataGridViewColumn();
cl.HeaderText = "Numbering";
grdCrew.Columns.Add(cl);
```

I want on every new row to put a number which is actually the number of the row, but i want to automatically assign the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
dataGridView1["ColumnName",rowIndex].DefaultNewRowValue = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Update :
Also you can use these codes :

```
adapter.Fill(dt);
        dt.Columns["ColumnName"].DefaultValue = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
yourColumn.DefaultValue = yourTable.Rows.Count;
```